# Cross domain posting using a proxy

Tags: php, jquery, curl, proxy, cross-domain

This works, certainly but when I add parameters it doesn't

```
<?php
    //set POST variables
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    unset($_POST['url']);
    $fields_string = "";
    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

When I tried ajax calls using jquery,

```
        var data = "url=http://www.domain/ajax/set.php&id=1413&index=0&action=add";
        $.ajax({
            url: "proxy.php",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('Success ' + data);

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error ' + jqXHR);
            }
        });
```

That should return null or "selected" . . . `selected` if successful on the first run and tried to run again, but both return null, excluding the `success` word of course.

I'm pretty sure that the params are correct, I used postman to check.

Comment: Since it's cross domain. You can POST all you want but you won't get a response back

Comment: I doubt that, I am receiving response though.

Comment: It's what you said. You received NULL as the response

Comment: I said, I suppose to receive null or selected., please read.

Comment: Using AJAX, it will always return an EMPTY response because it's cross-domain.

Comment: i doubt that, i am not receiving EMPTY response, you should try though.

Comment: Ok, sry. It will works if you use PHP curl. But try to var_dump every variable to see if they has the right value. Also do an echo of $result to send back to the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

```
set.php&id=1413
       ^
```

Did you mean?

```
set.php?id=1413
       ^
```